# Compilation of Encrypted C FIle

Tags: c, encryption

Actually, there is a way to open a file to set encryption key or password so that it cannot be open by any other user(other than who knows) using

vim -x test.c  (say file name is test.c)

It will ask the for Encryption Key and then we can write the code.

But when i compile with gcc(in Linux) or cc(In solaris), it gives some list of errors like below:

```
 encrypted.c", line 1: invalid source character: <0x17>
"encrypted.c", line 1: invalid source character: <0xffffff96>
"encrypted.c", line 1: invalid source character: <0xffffffd8>
"encrypted.c", line 1: invalid source character: <0xffffffa9>
"encrypted.c", line 1: invalid source character: <0xffffffcc>
```

Is there any way to compile this encryption file or i am doing something wrong while doing compilation(is it like invalid to do so)

Below is the code for test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CUBE(x) ((x)*(x)*(x))

int main()
{
int x = 5;
int val;
val = CUBE(++x);
printf("val is: %d",val);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "encrypted"?  Obviously, your compiler will not know how to deal with encrypted source code.

Comment: well if the file is encrypted, it's not exactly a c source code file anymore so how do you expect gcc to read this?

Comment: @ascii-lime how to set the character encoding in the editor

Comment: @stijn : that means it is completely invalid to do so?

Comment: I think gcc expects ASCII or Unicode input files. An encrypted file is binary, so the easiest solution is not encrypting at all, or first decrypting then compiling

Comment: CUBE(++x) invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Pipe the file through something that will decrypt it and then pipe the output to the compiler. As there are many options how to encrypt a file, you should do it yourself, you can't expect the compiler to do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Makefile which will compile exactly one .c file per gcc execution. Then you will need to make gcc read source code from stdin. Then you will need to have an decryption tool which will output the decrypted source code to stdout, so you can pipe it to gcc.

You could expand this solution by creating a wrapper script/program to interpret compiler command line and call real compiler with appropriately modified arguments, piping the unencrypted source code to compiler (possibly executing it several times if there were many source files in single command line). This way you could use existing Makefiles.

But, first step to make this work is, you need that decryption tool which can output to stdout, so you can pipe that to compiler. `vim` can probably do this for you, with right command line...